# iOS RSA Encryption using SSH Public Key

Tags: ios, encryption, ssh-keys

I am able to successfully encrypt (iOS) and decrypt on PHP side using an OpenSSL public/private key pair. If anyone needs an example please let me know. Only took all day and will be happy to share.

However, I was wondering if anyone has been able to do the same using a public/private key pair from SSH. That is what is generated from ssh-keygen. When I use the public key from the generated public/private keys, the application errors out with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to use the public key provided. So, I'm not even able to get to the point at which I'm even encrypting to send to the server to decrypt.

```
    // ERRORS AS NOTED BELOW   
    //NSString *myCertString = @"AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAAAgQDQexvBUxaBWRtbSkj7puZNw4rqUD1FhhYCEogpS5GwMir9mZOuOw9aGQmTJ0DmYY84/m890t8wnbWHcIk1D/TDMeDP2OSRHz4FtkPMt2G1Pf1lkvEhd9S5PvL2y/vwnvqhjIOYzqvIamnYloOwXQZ5lKcYxuFu7btMLYr1Rd1jtw==";

//WORKS
NSString *myCertString = @"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";

    NSData *myCertData = [base64 decodeBase64WithString:myCertString];//[[base64 decodeBase64WithString:myCertString] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    SecCertificateRef cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData (kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFDataRef)myCertData);
    CFArrayRef certs = CFArrayCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (const void **) &cert, 1, NULL);

    SecPolicyRef policy = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509();

    SecTrustRef trust;
    SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(certs, policy, &trust);

    SecTrustResultType trustResult;
    SecTrustEvaluate(trust, &trustResult);
    publicKey = SecTrustCopyPublicKey(trust); <-- ERRORS with EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

Any thoughts would be great. Or, does iOS just not support SSH public key encryption? Many thanks for any advice or guidance in the right direction.

Comment: You call function without checking their return value (`SecTrustCreateWithCertificates`, `SecTrustEvaluate`), I suggest starting by checking those...

Comment: I'm getting closer...it's pretty much down to the fact that the public key I have to work with doesn't have a certificate either associated with it or isn't include so there are no 'certs' any ideas on how I may be able to get around that?
SecCertificateRef cert is null and CFArrayRef is an array with a null certificate.
2014-02-17 23:00:32.688 Banter[15430:70b] cert: (null)
2014-02-17 23:00:32.688 Banter[15430:70b] certs: (
    (null)
)

Answer (score 0):

For security reason, you are not able to encrypt with exactly only the public key on iOS easily. Encryption on iOS requires a lot, that is why it is in the Security framework.

To use a RSA public key to encrypt data on iOS, you have to cheat iOS that this key is generated by itself.

See this question: [Encryption with RSA public key on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28291609/encryption-with-rsa-public-key-on-ios/28291683) It gives you the solution, and the full code demo on GitHub.