# Encryption with RSA public key on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption

I write an iOS app to communicate with an existing server. The server generates RSA key pair(public key and private key), and sends public key to the client.

The client(the iOS app) have to encrypt with ONLY the public key, and sends the encrypted data to server.

So, I need a Objective-C function to do RSA encryption.

**Input:**

- Plain text: hello world!
- The public key:

  ```
  -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
  MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDEChqe80lJLTTkJD3X3Lyd7Fj+
  zuOhDZkjuLNPog3YR20e5JcrdqI9IFzNbACY/GQVhbnbvBqYgyql8DfPCGXpn0+X
  NSxELIUw9Vh32QuhGNr3/TBpechrVeVpFPLwyaYNEk1CawgHCeQqf5uaqiaoBDOT
  qeox88Lc1ld7MsfggQIDAQAB
  -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
  ```

**Process:**

```
+ (NSString *)encryptString:(NSString *)str publicKey:(NSString *)pubKey;
```

**Output:**

`uwGuSdCgDxAAN3M5THMrNcec3Fm/Kn+uUk7ty1s70oH0FNTAWz/7FMnEjWZYOtHe37G3D4DjqiWijyUCbRFaz43oVDUfkenj70NWm3tPZcpH8nsWYevc9a1M9GbnNF2jRlami8LLUTZiogypSVUuhcJvBZBOfea9cOonX6BG+vw=`

**Question:**

How to implement this function?

```
+ (NSString *)encryptString:(NSString *)str publicKey:(NSString *)pubKey;
```

I have had digg for a long time, on SO and google and Apple's document. I found out Apple need a .der file to do encryption, not only the public key.

Answer (score 21):

I will answer my qustion:

### 1. create SecKeyRef with public key string

I am helped by this post: http://blog.flirble.org/2011/01/05/rsa-public-key-openssl-ios/#its-all-in-the-format

It led to my code: https://github.com/ideawu/Objective-C-RSA/blob/master/RSA.m#L34

### 2. use the SecKeyRef to encrypt input data

Use Apple's `SecKeyEncrypt`(https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/index.html)

### 3. the full code on github

https://github.com/ideawu/Objective-C-RSA

Comment: @Sosily I don't know what the tag is for, really don't know. but it is necessary to make it work.

Comment: Sorry this question is a bit out of context but here it goes. I am using your class (from above github lib) to (only) encrypt data using a public key. Then I send encrypted data to server. Can you pls tell me how this affects export compliance? (Current live version already uses https)

Comment: how can an iOS app get the Private key from the server? Can I generate the private key from the certificate?

Comment: @LeeProbert There is a php script demo https://github.com/ideawu/Objective-C-RSA#the-php-script-for-testing

Comment: It the server would have to send me the private key. Not secure.

Comment: it supports only openssh public key format? and not other formats like PKCS#1

Comment: Comment by [zonzi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7541630/zonzi) from this delete [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56794603/5292302) *"the public key code seems at line #L34 instead of line #L69. the code for 1. it should be https://github.com/ideawu/Objective-C-RSA/blob/master/RSA.m#L34"*

Comment: I have updated the link. Of course it would be better to include the relevant code here or to link to a specific revision instead to a constantly changing master branch

Answer (score 1):

- If you are using your public and private keys then use **SecKeyRef**
  to generate both keys else use keys provided by backend guys to communicate with server.
- These are some third party sdks that can help for this purpose, i've used one of them that helped me a lot to encrypt and decrypt.

[1]: https://github.com/Kitura/Swift-JWT   [2]: https://github.com/TakeScoop/SwiftyRSA   [3]: https://github.com/soyersoyer/SwCrypt   [4]: https://github.com/Kitura/BlueRSA

For further info visit below Apple link for official documentation
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security